# Compiling and packging FFmpeg with special configuration

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to compile FFmepg with specific configuration, that support nvidia cuda hardware acceleration.
In order to achive that, I'm compiling the code using the nvidia-cude-10.2 devel docker image.

I want to take the files I compiled and move them to a python alpine docker after which.

question is, if i follow the instructions [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

to be exact this part

> ```
>    cd ~/ffmpeg_sources && \
>    wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
>    tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
>    cd ffmpeg && \
>    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
>      --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
>      --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
>      --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
>      --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
>      --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
>      --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
>      --enable-gpl \
>      --enable-gnutls \
>      --enable-libaom \
>      --enable-libass \
>      --enable-libfdk-aac \
>      --enable-libfreetype \
>      --enable-libmp3lame \
>      --enable-libopus \
>      --enable-libvorbis \
>      --enable-libvpx \
>      --enable-libx264 \
>      --enable-libx265 \
>      --enable-nonfree && \
>    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
>    make install && \
>    hash -r
> ```

and than copy the files in the $HOME/bin directory will it be enough?

Should I use cuda container instead of python alpine and install python on it? I'm not sure if the cuda runtime is required after compilation

Comment: I don't see `--enable-cuda` in the configuration. Are you sure this has CUDA support?

Comment: @thekamilz
Sorry for the confusion, I just copy that part from the guide as an example
we are using 
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg &&\
    cd FFmpeg && \
    ./configure \
    --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid  \
    --enable-nvenc --enable-gpl  \
    --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp \
    --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include \
    --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 \
    --enable-zlib --enable-openssl && \
    make -j16 && \
    make install &&

Answer (score 1):

Ok, After `make install` you can call FFmpeg from where `bindir` is set. And you will be good to go.

Comment: After compiling i copied it to another container and i'm getting the following error
/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libnppig.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I guess copying just the bin folder wasn't enough?

Comment: Ok, solved the issue, to run with cuda special options you need to use a container that has cuda runtime